# Reputation out of sync on community wiki reversal

Tags: bug, reputation, community-wiki, reputation-audit

[My account on History](https://history.stackexchange.com/users/4058/athari) (274 reputation). Result of [reputation calculation](https://history.stackexchange.com/reputation):

> ** rep today: 0
>   ** rep this week (2014-04-20 - 2014-04-26): 0
>   ** rep this month (2014-04-01 - 2014-04-30): 5
>   ** rep this quarter (2014-04-01 - 2014-06-30): 5
>   ** rep this year (2014-01-01 - 2014-12-31): 328
>   ** rep from bonuses: 100
>   ** total rep 329 :)

`reputation?recalc=true` is disabled and displays the following message now:

> We have disabled this ability because reputation should be in sync without any user intervention.
>   If it's not in sync for more than 5 minutes, **it's a bug**.  We need to investigate that bug and a recalc hinders fixing the actual cause.

Desync is caused by my question becoming a community wiki and then being reversed by a moderator several days later. I guess this is a known case of lost reputation, but none the less, either Reputation report needs to be fixed or reputation needs to be recalculated on CW status reversal.

Comment: Although newer, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233944/reputation-does-not-update-after-community-wiki-is-removed-from-a-post-and-does) has an answer, so this should be closed as a duplicate.