# Reputation does not update after community wiki is removed from a post, and does not match the value displayed in the reputation audit

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, community-wiki, reputation-audit

If votes were cast on a post while it was community wiki, and a moderator removes wiki from that post, the votes should count towards reputation again. However, while this is visible in a reputation audit, [it fails to register in the displayed reputation on the site proper](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/8091/reputation-audit-does-not-match-reputation-on-site), and the reputation score needs to be recalculated to reflect the change.

Can someone fix this?

Comment: Nope, that's not a bug. There's no reputation for votes cast while the post is CW, even if CW is later removed

Comment: @Yannis: As currently implemented, when community wiki is removed, the system does not know the period during which the post was wiki. The result is a mismatch between the audit and the displayed reputation. As to which value should be considered correct, I don't know, but I have always tended to assume the audit always gives the correct reputation score.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting with `rev 2014.6.12.2312` here on meta and `rev 2014.6.12.1659` everywhere else, we're going to automatically recalculate the author's reputation when community wiki status is removed from a post.

Comment: Whoohoo! Now I *dare* you to remove CW status from Bobince's [parsing HTML with regex post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)! :-D

Comment: I support this idea! He will get about 40k then?

Comment: I haven't looked, but I bet the daily rep cap would get in the way for a lot of that. Don't forget that the votes would count for the days they were originally cast on.

Comment: The post went CW because the question attracted more than 30 answers, but I think he deserves to get credit for the post, whatever that may be.

Comment: It's not the hard to do either. Just unlock the post, un-CW his answer, then relock the post.

Comment: With all due respect to bobince, I don't think there's anything about his answer that makes it more deserving to be exempt from CW conversion than all the other good answers out there that ran into the same thing. Having said that, whether or not we *should* auto-convert to CW past a certain # of answers is a discussion worth having.

Comment: @AnnaLear We had that discussion, and auto-CW is gone. So this only applies to old questions now.

Comment: @MadScientist I thought we only removed it for auto-CW due to edits?

Comment: Grace wrote that all triggers were removed.